# Merge all JS into a single bundle.js | webpack 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using a Vuetify theme and trying to bundle all the JS code into a single bundle.js, but the code is generating in chunks, here is vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: false,
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false,
      concatenateModules: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
      //path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
      //outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/private'),
      //formats: ['iife'],
      filename: 'asset/js/[name].js',
      chunkFilename: 'asset/js/[name].js' 
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@vuetify-themes/material-dashboard-pro",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "dev": "yarn serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "postversion": "node scripts/postversion.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-meta": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.13",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "vuex-pathify": "^1.4.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vuetify/vue-cli-plugin-preset-base": "~0.3.2",
    "archiver": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-config-vuetify": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-chartist": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to bundle all the JS in a single file and CSS in a separate CSS file like style.css

This is what I'm getting right now.

[image]

Edit:

The filename is replaced to main.js

```
filename: 'asset/js/main.js'
```

It shows this error.

[image]

The source can be downloaded from here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMhgr1uphmS9JQnfIi-pHAK1u8l--15y/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

splitChunks accepts an object, providing a boolean you've disabled merging.

```
optimization: {
      // remove this line.
      splitChunks: false,
}
```

See the docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) if you want to configure it. By default it splits after more than 250kb (should be fine for you).

Comment: @mathiasgiger it doesn't work, I got the splitChunks for here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/932 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `concatenateModules` to `false` and remove `chunkFilename: 'asset/js/[name].js'`

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that, it is still the same, generating a large number of files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `filename` with desired value:

```
filename: 'asset/js/main.js'
```

then in `configureWebpack` remove `chunkFilename` and add:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
],
```

Comment: @MZH This solution works with the project downloaded from the Vuetify theme page.